# How to set up bluebird's config in browser

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I’m getting an issue when trying to set up bluebird’s config in the browser with browserify. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
window.Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.config({
    cancellation: true,
});
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error that `Promise.config is not a function.`

Here’s a screenshot of my code:
[image: bluebird error and console.log]

I'm using v3.4.1 and am trying to follow the docs here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html

Anyone have any ideas as to how to rememdy this situation? I'd like to use cancellable bluebird Promises in the browser, but to do so requires setting up the config.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(Promise)`?

Comment: @Gothdo I added that to the image. It looks like it is a function Promise(resolver)